# Coupled Mode Equation for Fiber Couplers

Tags: coupled-oscillators

I have a very specific question about coupled mode equations in fiber couplers. 
I read from the book "Applications of Nonlinear Fiber Optics", Govind P. Agrawal.

My question is in page 65 at the top :  $n_L$ is the linear part of $\tilde{n}$ at the equation 2.1.7. 
The whole concept deals with the derivation of coupled mode equations for fiber couplers , in a few words we have two fiber cores which interacts each other and whose fundamental modes overlap each other. So i just want to express the change of amplitude of each of the cores. And i have stuck at the point which seem below .I'm quoting the exact text below:

"\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial \tilde{A_1}}{\partial z } = i(\overline{\beta_1}+ \Delta\beta_1^{NL} - \beta) \tilde{A_1}+ i \kappa_{12}\tilde{A_2} 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial \tilde{A_2}}{\partial z } = i(\overline{\beta_2}+ \Delta\beta_2^{NL} - \beta) \tilde{A_2}+ i \kappa_{21}\tilde{A_1} 
\end{equation*}
where the coupling coefficient $\kappa_{mp}$ and the nonlinear contribution $\Delta\beta_m^{NL}$ are defined as ($m,p=1 $or $2$)
\begin{equation}
\kappa_{mp}=\frac{{k_0}^2}{2\beta}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\tilde{n}^2-n_p^2\right){F_m}^\ast F_m dx dy
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Delta \beta_{m}^{NL}=\frac{{k_0}^2}{2\beta}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\tilde{n}^2-n_L^2\right){F_m}^\ast F_m dx dy
\end{equation}
and $n_L$ is the linear part of $\tilde{n}$. We have assumed that the modal distributions are normalized such that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|F_m(x,y)|^2 dx dy =1$ ."

Where $\tilde{A_i}$ is the amplitude i mentioned , the refractive index is "$\tilde{n}=n_0$ everywhere in the x-y plane except in the region occupied by the two fiber cores , where is is larger by a constant amount"  . Similarly "$n_m=n_0$ everywhere in the x-y plane except in the region occupied by the m-th core in the absence of the other core".

Comment: If you include a quote of the relevant part of the book, you might get an answer from somebody who knows about fiber couplers but doesn't happen to own that book.

Comment: Yes please expand and provide some details about the notation and context of your problem.

Comment: It's a little bit lengthy, the derivation i mentioned consisted of some pages and i have a specific question at a very specific line . I was wondering if anyone can explain the concept of linear part of the refractive index $\tilde{n}$.

Comment: I actually don't see a question. This is fairly standard (and often not very accurate) stuff - overlap integrals. What concept are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't see where $n_L$ comes from ? there is no mention about that earlier . At the position of $\Delta \beta_{1}^{NL}$ i have found $\frac{{k_0}^2}{2\beta }\int\int \tilde{n}^2-{n_L}^2 F_1F_1^\ast$

Comment: $\frac{{k_0}^2}{2\beta }\int\int( \tilde{n}^2-{n_L}^2) F_1F_1^\ast$